# Conditional expressions on numerical data - Python/Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm, conditional-operator

Let me show you a situation like this:

```
data = [Station.objects
                        .filter(nr=form.cleaned_data['station'])
                        .aggregate(avg=Avg('residual'),
                                   stdev=StdDev('residual'),
                                   number=Count('residual'),
                                   good_observations = Count(Case(When(abs('residual')<250))),
                                   outliers=Count(Case(When(abs('residual')>=250))),
                                   )]
```

I want to count rows in database with "residual" (float value) smaller or greater than 250 but it doesn't work.

First of all: I've got the TypeEror:

> **init**() takes either a Q object or lookups as keyword arguments

Secondly:

abs() function doesn't work due to TypeError and string value as an input.

I hope some of you could help me with this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it states in the error message, the `__init__` of `When` takes keyword args or [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), very much like `QuerySet.filter`. You can can mimick `abs` using `Q` objects:

```
When(Q(residual__lt=250) & Q(residual__gt=-250))  # -250 < residual < 250
When(Q(residual__gte=250) | Q(residual__lte=-250))  # other cases
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem with TypeError but both count results show: 0 what is impossible when first count called "number" shows for example 210